# Error accessing memory(heap) in a simply programm

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-corruption

When I populate the array(doska) all is ok, but when I try to print element(`cout<<` I get error

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct doskas{
         int number;
        char ch;
    };
    int main(){
        auto doska= new doskas[8][8];
        auto ss="0abcdefgh";
        for(int i=1;i<=8;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=8;j++){
            doska[i][j].ch=ss[i];
            doska[i][j].number=j;
            }
        }

        for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
            for(int j=1;j<=8;j++){
                cout<<doska[i][j].ch;//ERROR
                cout<<doska[i][j].number;
            }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try from 0 and strictly less than 8, not from one to eight.

Comment: Or that, yes. But still, since indexes are 0-based, making boards 9 by 9 leaves you with extra cell per row and column and this is not necessarily what you wanted.

Comment: And if you do not change the for loops accordingly, you are going to neglect doska[0][0], doska[0][1] and doska[1][0] entirely! Surely something you do not want when looping over an array.

Comment: @ksming, that's more or less what I was talking about. He seems to want it, just treat it as 1-based 8x8 array. Which is somewhat… esthetically displeasing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Array indices must always start with 0 and end with N-1 where N is the size of the array. Please change your index variables in all the for loops accordingly. Like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
  //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to enumerate array indices in the half-open range `[0, N)`, and all is well:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
      doska[i][j].ch = ss[i];
      doska[i][j].number = j;
    }
  }
```

See Dijkstra's [famous argument](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) on why this is the sanest way to think about ranges.